# Selecting the nearest date from a list pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with a field 'Process Date' and another field 'Effective_date'.  The 'Effective_date' field contains a list of dates.  What I am trying to accomplish is select the date closest to the date contained in the 'Process Date' filed without going over. (In other words, the closest date from the past). For example, in the frame below, the first 'Process date' - 4/14/2014 in row [0] should match up to 3/2/2010.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
    Title Code Process Date Type  Title_code  \
0        40493     4/4/2014   SI       40493   
1        40493    4/18/2014   SI       40493   
2        40493     5/2/2014   SI       40493   
3        40493    5/16/2014   SI       40493   
4        40493    5/30/2014   SI       40493   
5        40493    6/13/2014   SI       40493   
6        10251    10/4/2013  RIP       10251   
7        40491   10/18/2013   LD       40491   
8        40491   10/18/2013   SI       40491   
9        40491    11/1/2013   LD       40491   
10       40491    11/1/2013   SI       40491   
11       40491   11/15/2013   LD       40491   
12       40491   11/15/2013   SI       40491   

                                       Effective_date  
0                ['3/2/2010', '3/3/2017', '9/3/2016']  
1                ['3/2/2010', '3/3/2017', '9/3/2016']  
2                ['3/2/2010', '3/3/2017', '9/3/2016']  
3                ['3/2/2010', '3/3/2017', '9/3/2016']  
4                ['3/2/2010', '3/3/2017', '9/3/2016']  
5                ['3/2/2010', '3/3/2017', '9/3/2016']  
6   ['9/3/2011', '9/3/2012', '9/3/2013', '9/3/2014...  
7                            ['9/3/2016', '3/2/2010']  
8                ['3/2/2010', '3/3/2017', '9/3/2016']  
9                            ['9/3/2016', '3/2/2010']  
10               ['3/2/2010', '3/3/2017', '9/3/2016']  
11                           ['9/3/2016', '3/2/2010']  
12               ['3/2/2010', '3/3/2017', '9/3/2016']
```

Comment: Are the dates stored as pd.datetimes objects or strings?

Comment: They are stored as datetimes, not strings. Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.searchsorted` to find where the date should be inserted. Your lists aren't sorted, so this needs to be done first. You have a list in a DataFrame, so none of this is going to be particularly fast. You need to search separately for each row, so we'll use a list comprehension:

#### Sample Data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from random import shuffle

df = pd.DataFrame({'Process Date': pd.date_range('2013-01-01', freq='3M', periods=10)})
l1 = pd.date_range('2012-01-01', freq='96D', periods=13).tolist()
shuffle(l1)  #So it isn't ordered
df['Effective_Date']= [l1 for i in range(10)]
```

#### Code:

```
df['Effective_Date'] = df['Effective_Date'].apply(np.sort)
df['Date_Before'] = [l[np.searchsorted(l, date)-1] 
                     for l,date in zip(df['Effective_Date'], df['Process Date'])]
```

#### Output:

`print(df[['Process Date', 'Date_Before']])`

```
  Process Date Date_Before
0   2013-01-31  2013-01-19
1   2013-04-30  2013-04-25
2   2013-07-31  2013-07-30
3   2013-10-31  2013-07-30
4   2014-01-31  2013-11-03
5   2014-04-30  2014-02-07
6   2014-07-31  2014-05-14
7   2014-10-31  2014-08-18
8   2015-01-31  2014-11-22
9   2015-04-30  2015-02-26
```

---

Given the indexing, this will cause issues if `'Process Date'` is before the earliest date in `'Effective_Date'` (you'll index with `-1` and grab the latest date). Probably simplest to fix that after the fact, or could add an `if-else` in the list comprehension.

```
df.loc[df.Date_Before.gt(df['Process Date']), 'Date_Before'] = pd.NaT
```